# AIR for iOS: Power saving

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, optimization, air, power-management

What coding tricks, compilation flags, software-architecture considerations can be applied in order to keep powerconsumption low in an AIR for iOS application (or to reduce powerconsumption in an existing application that burns too much battery)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the biggest things you can do is adjust the framerate based off of the app state.

You can do this by adding handlers inside your App.mxml

```
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                        activate="activate()" deactivate="close()" />
```

Inside your activate and close methods

```
//activate
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.frameRate = 24;

//deactivate
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.frameRate = 2;
```

You can also play around with this number depending on what your app is currently doing. If you're just displaying text try lowering your fps. This should give you the most bang for your buck power savings.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, high power consumption can be the result of:

- intensive network usage
- no sleep mode for display while app idle
- un-needed location services usage
- continously high usage of cpu

Regarding (flex/flash) AIR I would suggest that:

First you use the Flex profiler + task-manager and monitor CPU and Memory usage. Try to reduce them as much as possible. As soon as you have this low on windows/mac they will go lower (theoretically on mobile devices)

Next step would be to use a network monitor and reduce the amount and size of the network (webservice) calls. Try to identify unneeded network activity and eliminate it.

Try to detect any idle state of the app (possible in flex, not sure about flash) and maybe put the whole app in an idle mode (if you have fireworks animation running then just call  stop())

Also I am not sure about it, but will reduce for sure cpu and use more gpu: by using Stage3D (now available with air 3.2 also for mobile) when you do complex anymations. It may reduce execution time since HW accel is there, therefore power consumption may be lower.

If I am wrong about something please comment/downvote (as you like) but this is my personal impression.

**Update 1**

As prompted in the comments, there is not a 100% link between cpu usage on a desktop and on a mobile device, but "theoreticaly" on the low level we should have at least the same cpu usage trend.

Comment: You may also want to look at adjusting the framerate. Try lowering it whenever you're not animating or if the application is no longer in focus.

Comment: Not sure how well a desktop machine's task manager reflects the real CPU usage of an AIR app. Keep in mind that the compiled application (release build) will perform very different than the simulator. Personally I'd rather look at the compile time for methods that is displayed by the Flex profiler. If possible, a task manager on the device is probably the way to go if you want realistic CPU usage of a deployed application, though this is only possible with ICS on Android if I heard correct.

Comment: @Al_Birdy For sure the iPhone CPU has a completely different architecture that a desktop CPU, plus the AS code of the AIR app is translated to binary code iOS compatible, so for sure there is not a 100% match between the 2. But having a 100% cpu usage for your air app on the desktop for sure will generate high cpu usage on the mobile device aswell.

Comment: @lost  your are perfect right... lowering framerate is a good practice when app is in idle mode. :)

Comment: No question that a generally lower CPU consumption on the desktop will somehow reflect the CPU usage on the device, totally agree with you, but that is more a sledgehammer refactoring approach ;).

Comment: @Al_Birdy Since there is not real documentation from adobe / apple which can tell us certain things we can only use our "intuition" in making the apps perform better. This are my personal thoughts and What I would consider when building an mobile app with flex. :)

Answer (score 0):

My tips:

- Profile your App in a first step with the profiler from the Flash Builder
- If you have a Mac, profile your app with Instruments from XCode

And important:

behaviors of Simulator, IPA-Interpreter packages and IPA-Test builds are different.

Simulator - pro forma optimizations

IPA-Interpreter - Get a feeling of performance

IPA-Test - "real" performance behavior

And finally test the AppStore-Build, it is the fastest (in meaning of performance) package mode.
Additional we saw, that all this modes can vary.